# EFS volume not mounted on Docker container on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

I'm unable to mount an EFS volume on my Docker container running on Elastic Beanstalk.  Here's what I have in `Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/mydir",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/mydir"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's what I have in `.ebextensions/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config`.  The rest is the same as [this](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-docs/blob/master/.ebextensions/aws_provided/instance%20configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config).

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    EFS_VOLUME_ID: 'fs-*****'
    EFS_MOUNT_DIR: '/mydir'
```

When I ssh into my Elastic Beanstalk environment, I see that the volume is mounted on the host:

```
[ec2-user@ip-****** app]$ df
Filesystem                                                  1K-blocks    Used        Available Use% Mounted on
us-east-1a.fs-******.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ 9007199254740992       0 9007199254740992   0% /mydir
```

But in my Docker container, the filesystem is not EFS:

```
root@99046bd6a358:/reo# df
Filesystem                       1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1                         8125880 1552688   6472924  20% /mydir
```

I do not have any `VOLUME` instructions in my `Dockerfile`.

Furthermore, if I created a file in my Docker container, that file does not exist when I go back to the host directory.  Therefore,  `/mydir` is not coming from the hosts volume.  What else do I need to do access my EFS volume on Docker?

Comment: I ended up using AWS S3 to store my files.

Comment: I have exactly this issue, I don't want to use S3 though.

Comment: same problem here. crazy there is no solution for years, at least none that I know of